# new column base on multi column condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({

'cakeName':    ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
'chocolate%':  ['20','70','30','50','50','10','75','20'],
'milk%' :      ['50','20','40','0', '30','80','15','10'],
'straberry%' : ['30','10','30','50','20','10','10','70'],

})

df.head(10)
```

i would like to create a new column 'cakeType' based on the columns value

objective:
- scan through each cakeName
- if there are single ingredient which stand out, >= 75, then return a value in 'cakeType'
- for example: cake 'G'  chocolate% >= 75, then 'choco' etc
- else if none of the ingredient have more than 75, its just a 'normal cake'

i had seek for answer in forum, doesn't seem quite fit, as i will have many many ingredients column
so scanning the row looking for value >= 75 is a better way to do it?

thanks a lot

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Have you tried any solutions yourself? If so, let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1: `np.select`:

Good use case for [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) where we define our `conditions` and based on those conditions we select `choices`. Plus we have a `default` value if none of the conditions is met:

```
conditions = [
    df['chocolate%'].ge(75),
    df['milk%'].ge(75),
    df['straberry%'].ge(75)
]

choices = ['choco', 'milk', 'strawberry']

df['cakeType'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='normal cake')

  cakeName chocolate% milk% straberry%     cakeType
0        A         20    50         30  normal cake
1        B         70    20         10  normal cake
2        C         30    40         30  normal cake
3        D         50     0         50  normal cake
4        E         50    30         20  normal cake
5        F         10    80         10         milk
6        G         75    15         10        choco
7        H         20    10         70  normal cake
```

---

#### Method 2: `idxmax`, `Series.where` and `fillna`:

First we get the column names where a value is `>= 75`. Then we remove the column names which do not have `any` value `>= 75` and `fillna` them with `normal cake`

```
m1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].ge(75).idxmax(axis=1)
newcol = m1.where(df.iloc[:, 1:].ge(75).any(axis=1)).str[:-1].fillna('normal cake')

df['cakeType'] = newcol

  cakeName chocolate% milk% straberry%     cakeType
0        A         20    50         30  normal cake
1        B         70    20         10  normal cake
2        C         30    40         30  normal cake
3        D         50     0         50  normal cake
4        E         50    30         20  normal cake
5        F         10    80         10         milk
6        G         75    15         10    chocolate
7        H         20    10         70  normal cake
```

Comment: hi, may i ask why you want to have this in your Method 2: " str[:-1] " ?